# How can I retrieve data from the database when the date > now()

Tags: mysql

My purpose is since the time I login my page, I want my web to show how many updated data in the database. My code is like this

```
$current = $_SESSION['date'];
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM gmaptracker1 WHERE datetime >= '$current'";
```

When I echo the `$current`, it showed `27/09/14 : 06:53:24`, so the `$current` is correct, however, when I request the number of database where `date>='$current'`, I get zero, although I have inserted to the database the data with datetime `28/09/14 : 06:53:24` and `29/09/14 : 06:53:24`.

Can anyone help me to get out of this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things,

It seems like your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Just because you retrieve the content of the date from a session, it doesn't mean that it's safe.

Also, why do you need it to be in a session variable? If you always want to retrieve dates bigger than `NOW()` you can just write your query this way:

`SELECT * FROM gmaptracker1 WHERE datetime >= NOW()`

The part that caught my attention was the format you're storing the dates.

You said that when you echo'ed `$_SESSION['date']` the value was: **27/09/14 : 06:53:24**

Now, that does not look like the date format at all. Is your column actually a `datetime` or `timestamp`column?

If it's a `VARCHAR` or any other type other than `datetime` or `timestamp`, then there's no way for MySQL to know that you're trying to retrieve dates that occur in the future.

If you already have data stored, then it isn't going to be as easy as changing the data type because you already have data, and your data is in the wrong format. The format that MySQL stores datetime information is as follows:

`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Based on the comments you left, you don't need the time `> NOW()`, you need the time when you log in. Now it makes sense why you're storing that time in a variable.

The problem is the format you're storing it.

Since you're using PHP, then you have to store the time this way:

```
$time = new DateTime();
$_SESSION['date'] = $time->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Everything I was about to say and more.

Comment: I don't think so, when I request the data where datetime>='1992-07-01:00:00:00'. It worked correctly, It mean my format is correct. Besides, because I want to frequently update data table where show the data since I login , so I have to store the data to SESSION in order to not update the value of now()

Comment: @JasonSKY It worked correctly because you're using the right format. You wrote it down in your post. When you echo your variable's content it is in a different format. It isn't `YYYY-MM-DD HH::MM:SS` It looks like `YY/MM/DD : HH:MM:SS`

Comment: Also, why are you retrieving the date and time from a session, if you need the datetime to be `> NOW()`.  Skip the session altogether, and just use `> NOW()` in your query

Comment: It's difficult to help you further, the two lines of code you posted, that are completely unrelated to your issue. Without a sample of the actual data in your database and a description of your tables. We'll only be speculating about what could be possibly wrong.

Comment: I tried, but it say undefined function, also,  i don't  want to use now>() since it will continuously update the time, what I want is the value after the time I login

Comment: So, how can I store the time to a parameter when I login my page. What I did is I stored the time value into a session and then use that session for another php and in this php I store the value session into $current. Here is my code for storing time value into a session
{date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok"); 
     $_SESSION['date']=date("d/m/y : H:i:s", time());}